# MYSQL PROCEDURE for my nested Category Structure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure in MYSQL that will retrieve my data from my nested category structure:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| category_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id   | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| sequence    | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Example datas:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `category_id` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` VARCHAR(255),
  `description` VARCHAR(255),
  `parent_id` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `sequence` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `category_id` (`category_id`)
);
COMMIT;



/* Data for the `categories` table  (Records 1 - 14) */

INSERT INTO `categories` (`category_id`, `category`, `description`, `parent_id`, `sequence`)     VALUES 
  (2, 'Student Level', 'Students Level Grade...', 0, 0),
  (18, '3Ã¨me', NULL, 2, 1),
  (19, '5Ã¨me', NULL, 2, 2),
  (20, '6Ã¨me', NULL, 2, 3),
  (21, 'Lettres', NULL, 18, 0),
  (22, 'SÃ©quence I : En route pour le brevet', NULL, 21, 0),
  (23, 'SÃ©quence II : Jeannot et Colin', NULL, 21, 0),
  (24, 'SÃ©quence III : De l''Ã©ducation', NULL, 21, 0),
  (25, 'SÃ©quence IV : Pauline', NULL, 21, 0),
  (26, 'SÃ©quence V : Å’dipe roi', NULL, 21, 0),
  (27, 'SÃ©quence VI : La planÃ¨te des singes', NULL, 21, 0),
  (28, 'SÃ©quence VII : La poÃ©sie engagÃ©e', NULL, 21, 0),
  (29, 'Blog Categories', 'Blog Categories', 0, 0),
  (30, 'Blog', 'Default Blog', 29, 0);
```

I wish to create a function that I will call for example call `GetFormatCategories()` that will return the following fields and values:

field > value

**category_id** > its original category_id value
**category** > its original category value
**sequence** > its original sequence
**parent_id** > its original parent_id
**level** > for example (Student Level = 1), (3Ã¨me = 2), (Lettres = 3) (SÃ©quence I : En route pour le brevet = 4) the level of the categories by its hierarchy

the result should be sorted by level, for example:

```
 Level 1
      Level 2
           Level 3
                Level 4
                Level 4
                Level 4
                Level 4
                Level 4
           Level 3
                Level 4
                Level 4
      Level 2
           Level 3
                Level 4
                Level 4
```

I've tried using various examples, like http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/nesting-mysql-cursor-loops.html, but I still have problems:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE `catlist`()
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    -- Done Trigger
    DECLARE tDone boolean default false;

    -- Possible Field i Need to Use
    DECLARE vCatID INT;
    DECLARE vCatName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE vParentID INT;
    DECLARE vSequence INT;
    DECLARE vLevel INT;

    DECLARE topCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT `category_id`,`category`,`parent_id`,`sequence` FROM `level_category`;
    DECLARE subCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT `category_id`,`category`,`parent_id`,`sequence` FROM `categories` WHERE parent_id = vCatID;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET tDone := TRUE;


    -- Create Temporary tblResult to handle Query Results
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tblResults;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblResults (
        `category_id` int(11),
        `category` varchar(255),
        `parent_id` int(11),
        `sequence` int(11),
        `level` int(11),
         PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)

    );


    SET vLevel = 0;

    OPEN topCursor;    
    TopLoop : LOOP -- Top Loop Begin
        FETCH topCursor INTO vCatID, vCatName, vParentID, vSequence;
        REPLACE INTO tblResults VALUES (vCatID, vCatName, vParentID, vSequence, vLevel);
        IF tDone THEN
            CLOSE topCursor;
            LEAVE TopLoop;
        END IF;


        OPEN subCursor;    
        SubLoop : LOOP
            FETCH subCursor INTO vCatID, vCatName, vParentID, vSequence;
            REPLACE INTO tblResults VALUES (vCatID, vCatName, vParentID, vSequence, vLevel);
            IF tDone THEN
                SET vLevel = vLevel + 1;
                set tDone := false;
                CLOSE subCursor;
                LEAVE SubLoop;
            END IF;


        END LOOP SubLoop;



    END LOOP TopLoop; -- Top Loop End



    SELECT * FROM tblResults;

END;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.com! Could you explain a little more about what you were expecting to see, and what errors you have?

Comment: what i really want to get is i will have LEVEL of current category data and its sort value, its somewhat like a tree category. its actually possible with php + mysql, but i want to see if its possible in just pure MYSQL. :D

Comment: If you guys are interested on the solution i did it via MYSQL VIEW ONLY :) you can see the solution here 

https://github.com/phatneglo/mysql-nested-category-table-view